# Mongoose's Model.countDocuments() returning 'InternalError'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

While attempting to count documents using [Model.countDocuments()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.countDocuments) I'm presented with the message `MongoError: [ActivityId=...] Internal error`. See below for the full stack trace. All other database operations seem to work, including [Model.estimatedDocumentCount()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount). Unfortunately I need to use Model.countDocuments() because some collections contain multiple document types which Model.estimatedDocumentCount() can't account for.

The code is as follows. It's good to note my `getModel` function is in a seperate module which initiates the database connection (if not already active) and return the Model object corresponding with the value of the `item` URL parameter. Furthermore, when I change `countDocuments` to `find`, I'm getting the documents collection without any errors.

```js
module.exports = async (context, req) => {
    const result = {
        status: 404,
        body: "{}"
    }

    try {
        if (req.params.hasOwnProperty("item")) {
            const model = await getModel(String(req.params.item))

            if (model !== null) {
                await model.countDocuments({}).then(r => {
                    result.status = 200
                    result.body = JSON.stringify(r)
                    console.log(r)
                })
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        result.status = 500
        result.body = JSON.stringify({ error: error })
        console.log(error)
    }
    
    return result
}
```

I'm using `mongoose@^5.12.3` to connect with my Microsoft Azure Cosmos Emulator 2.11.11 (with the `/EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6` flag) using the following connection settings:

```js
instance = await mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb://${process.env.COSMOSDB_HOST}:${process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT}/${process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME}?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb`,
    {
        auth: {
            user: process.env.COSMOSDB_USER,
            password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
        },
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        retryWrites: false,
        sslValidate: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED ? false : true,
        useFindAndModify: false, // https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify
        autoIndex: false // https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes
    }
)
```

This is the full stack trace:

```
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.151Z] MongoError: [ActivityId=323a3824-3b2c-488b-9e56-05a0541bc88d] Internal error.
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.153Z]     at MessageStream.messageHandler (...\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.156Z]     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.158Z]     at processIncomingData (...\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.160Z]     at MessageStream._write (...\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.163Z]     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.165Z]     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.167Z]     at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.169Z]     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.171Z]     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.176Z]     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.178Z]     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.180Z]     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.182Z]   ok: 0,
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.185Z]   code: 1,
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.187Z]   codeName: 'InternalError'
[2021-04-06T18:48:31.189Z] }
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4phNZ.png  I tried this and it worked,

Comment: If you got any progress? Pls feel free to share your further problems here if exists.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your test code, @Tiny-wa! Unfortunately I'm getting the same error when I print `err` in the callback of `countDocuments({})` after printing `count`. As mentioned in my initial post I'm using the Azure Cognos DB Emulator, so I tried replacing the connection string to that of a real Azure-hosted Cognos DB, and it worked fine. I guess it's a bug in the emulator...

`[2021-04-16T05:48:11.470Z] ====================
[2021-04-16T05:48:11.471Z] undefined
[2021-04-16T05:48:11.472Z] MongoError: [ActivityId=...] Internal error.`

Comment: Basically, cosmosdb emulator really has much problems as it didn't update for a long time and I really tested with a real azure cosmosdb account. Anyway, that's good for you to solve the problem. Could you pls accept my post as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = "copy from azure portal-> cosmosdb mongo instance-> quickstart-> nodejs-> primary connection string";
var db = mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.connection.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("link error：" + error);
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("success");
  });

var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : { type:String },
    home : { type:String },
    age  : { type:Number, default:0 },
    time : { type:Date, default:Date.now },
    email: { type:String,default:''}
});

var PersonModel = mongoose.model("families", PersonSchema);

var personEntity = new PersonModel({
    name : "zf",
    age  : 6,
    email: "zf@cosmos.com",
    home:'asdf'
});

// personEntity.save(function (err, doc) {
//     if (err) return console.error(err);
//     console.error(doc);
//   });

PersonModel.countDocuments({},function(err, count){
    console.log("====================");
    console.log(count);
})
```

[image]